# How do I deference the address (examine memory) stored at label in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, nasm

> How do I deference the address (examine memory) stored at label in GDB?

I've produced the example below, where I try to examine the memory address stored as a doubleword value at label `file_handle`. In this case, the address is 0, but in general, it could be arbitrary. Each attempt makes `x` examine address `0x401004`, and not `0x00` as anticipated.

I know I could just copy paste the address and give it to `x` as argument, but I'm used to using the * operator to deference values stored in registers, e.g., `x *$eax`.

How can I use the same technique to deference to address stored at label without copy-pasting it?

```
    (gdb) x &file_handle
    0x401004 <file_handle>: 0x00000000
    (gdb) x *&file_handle
    0x401004 <file_handle>: 0x00000000
    (gdb) x *(&file_handle +0x00)
    0x401004 <file_handle>: 0x00000000
```

Comment: Simply `x file_handle`

Comment: Are you sure? I will try that out now. Why are label notation not consistent with other notation for looking up memory?

Comment: If you're debugging a target where a C pointer is the same size as the addresses you're using, try `x *(char **)file_handle`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have a program:

```
section .data
file_handle db "some"
...
```

Via `x &file_handle` we examine memory by an address of `file_handle`.

```
0x601038 <file_handle>: 0x656d6f73
```

If we wanna examine memory by where the content of `file_handle` points to we can try:

```
x *file_handle
```

But we got an error: `'file_handle' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type`

So, after casting to char (because we're dealing with `db`):

```
x *(char *)file_handle
```